# Cmake does not find boost 1.51 (windows 8)

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I am trying to compile mlpack (http://www.mlpack.org/) which requires boost.
First I installed boostpro 1.51 (http://www.boostpro.com/download/) and boost is now installed in C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51

Then I compiled and installed armadillo (another dependancy of mlpack) using cmake and mingw32-make. Boost is also a dependency of armadillo. Following some advises ([Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)), I added to the CMakeLists file:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51\\lib")
```

Things went smoothly.

Now I am trying to run CMake on mlpack but get this error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoos
>   t.cmake:1192 (message):
>    Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.51.0
>
> Boost include path: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_51
>
> The following Boost libraries could not be found:
>
> ```
>      boost_program_options
>      boost_unit_test_framework
> ```
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
>     directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
>     Boost.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:192 (find_package)

I tried to add (as for armadillo), but no improvement:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51\\lib")
```

Then I tried to add as well:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:\\Program Files\\boost\\boost_1_51\\lib")
```

For the BOOST_INCLUDEDIR, I really do not know which folder I should point too. boost_1_51 contains: bin, boost, dist, doc, lib, libs, more

I also tried this ([cmake is using the wrong cboost libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443931/cmake-is-using-the-wrong-cboost-libs)), without success.

I am also a little confused as armadillo seemed to have compiled without issues (or I missed something ?)

Many thanks

Note: content of the cmakelists file:

```
#Unfortunately this configuration variable is necessary and will need to be
#updated as time goes on and new versions are released.
set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.41" "1.41.0" "1.42" "1.42.0" "1.43" "1.43.0" "1.44" "1.44.0" "1.45.0" "1.46.0" "1.46.1" "1.47.0" "1.48.0" "1.49.0" "1.51.0")
find_package(Boost
    COMPONENTS
      program_options
      unit_test_framework
    REQUIRED
)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I added 1.51.0 myself.

---

from what I understood from another post ([CMake not finding Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280823/cmake-not-finding-boost?rq=1)) this might be related to not finding libraries with correct names. In my lib folder I have (dll and lib files):

```
boost_program_options-vc80-mt-1_51.dll
boost_program_options-vc80-mt-gd-1_51.dll
boost_program_options-vc100-mt-1_51.dll
boost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.dll
```

somehow I am supposed to play with commands like

```
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
```

so that it will look for the lib with the expected name ????

Comment: Can you rerun cmake with -DBoost_DEBUG=ON and post the output?  Also, are you invoking cmake with the generator specified as `"MinGW Makefiles"`?  The boost libs you've listed are for use with Visual C++ (note the `vc` in their names).

Comment: I am pretty certain the above comment is the problem. The 2 versions of boost found are for VC 2005 and VC 2010. Neither will work with mingw. Boost needs to be built with mingw for this to work.

Comment: thanks. At the end I re-compiled boost and this problem disappear. Now I have problems for compiling using make, "undefined reference to boost::program_options:: ...". About the version of boost for VC, I am new to c++ and confused: I thought compiled libraries were specific to OS/CPU. Libraries can be specific to an IDE as well ?